# Re-enable WebGL without restarting Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

When Chrome stops WebGL and gives you the following error (in a yellow banner on top of the screen): ["Rats! WebGL hit a snag..."](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2905826?hl=en), and reloading does not work (WebGL is still not re-enabled), **is it possible to re-enable WebGL without restarting Chrome?**

Context:

- Chrome disables WebGL probably because it requires too many resources: I ask it to display 400,000 billboards on Cesium, for those who know what this is.
- I know how I could reduce the resources my app asks for, but actually I am exploring its limits for testing purposes. So I am going to make Chrome disable WebGL a lot of times, and I do not want to restart it everytime it disables WebGL.

My configuration:

- Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m
- Windows 7 Pro 64 bit.

Solutions explored:

- I already tried to open a new Chrome window, it does not work. For the moment all I can do is close all Chrome windows and restart it.
- I already tried to put --ignore-gpu-blacklist in the Chrome shortcut (even if I understood this is for Windows XP, right?).

Hope I was clear enough.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Wish I knew, Shadertoy causes Chrome to crash it's WebGL implementation  frequently, and I'd love to be able to get it to reload WebGL *every* time, not just once or twice and then stop offering.

Comment: I'd love an answer to this as well. For me (and some others on linux) restarting chrome doesn't help either. A workaround for this I've found is to reset all to default in chrome://flags/ and then use the restart button that pops up. Consider yourself lucky that you can just restart I guess, OP. =P

Comment: @dgiugg: Same here on Win 10 + Chrome 46.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and I just found a solution. It sounds like this didn't work back when this question was posted but, it works now!

Refreshing the page doesn't work. If you clicked a link from a different tab to open the tab the crashed, clicking that link again doesn't work. You have to open a new tab and paste in the URL of the page that you want to reload.

I'm guessing this is due to chrome threading... by opening a brand new tab, you create a new thread instead of using the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

In your application you should properly handle `webglcontextlost` and `webglcontextrestored` events. In particular, you should prevent default event action in `webglcontextlost` handler thus telling the browser that you can restore proper functioning of your app when `webglcontextrestored` will be fired.